# jQuery How to display the hidden Nxt button when there's a value in Input Type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there's a value in the Input. If there is, the NEXT button will display.

Here's my logic

```
$('.regform input').on('click', function() {
        if($(".firstname").val()!="" && $(".email").val()!="" && $(".password").val()!="") {
            $(".submit .myButton").css({
                display: "block",
                visibility: "visible"
            }
        )}; 
    });
```

This is a 5 step form. Currently, the Next Button is display none. So when the step in on the Input type, the Next Button is display none. But when you insert values on Input type, the button will reveal.

Here's my html

```html
<form id="regform" method="post" action="http://blahblah.com/signup">
  <div class="steps step1">
    <label>Your Gender?</label>
    <div name="gender">
      <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
        <span>Man</span>
        <div class="man"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="woman-btn" value="2">
        <span>Woman</span>
        <div class="woman"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="steps step2">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="steps step3">
    <label>What is Your Date of Birth?</label>
    <select name="dobday" id="dobday" class="required">
   <option value="">Day</option>
   <option value="1">01</option>
   <option value="2">02</option>
   <option value="3">03</option>
   <option value="4">04</option>
   <option value="5">05</option>
   <option value="6">06</option>
   <option value="7">07</option>
   <option value="8">08</option>
   <option value="9">09</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="23">23</option>
   <option value="24">24</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="26">26</option>
   <option value="27">27</option>
   <option value="28">28</option>
   <option value="29">29</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
    <select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth" class="required">
   <option value="">Month</option>
   <option value="1">January</option>
   <option value="2">February</option>
   <option value="3">March</option>
   <option value="4">April</option>
   <option value="5">May</option>
   <option value="6">June</option>
   <option value="7">July</option>
   <option value="8">August</option>
   <option value="9">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
    <select name="dobyear" id="dobyear" class="required">
   <option value="">Year</option>
   <?php for($x=date("Y") - 18; $x >= 1918; $x--): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
   <?php endfor; ?>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="steps step4">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="steps step5">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="error">This field is required</div>
</form>
<div class="submit">
 <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Next">
</div>
```

Please help me with this situation.

Comment: please add your html code as well.

Comment: You've added a requirement, and some code, but you haven't said what your code does, whether you're code works, and whether it's producing any errors. You need to ask a specific *question* for us to provide useful answers.

Comment: Code like this can work, and if it's not working it's only a guess as to why without seeing the html. Having said that, I suspect you would do better using form validation for things like this - it will save you some headaches: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: @Dij i've inserted my html

Comment: @meagar i've edited my question now

Comment: @KobeBryan where is the button in your html that you want to show?

Comment: @Dij in the 2nd step. In first name. When you type values on the Input Type, the button will reveal. Currently, i've make it to display: none. That should trigger the button. See my jquery script above.

Comment: @KobeBryan that is alright, but I can't see the button anywhere in the html, how are you going to show it if its not even there.

Comment: @Dij my bad! i've updated the html.

Comment: @KobeBryan added a solution, check that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to attach event handler to keypress event of inputs, click event won't work here. Then your selectors for inputs is wrong, you are using class selectors but you need to select using name. something like this works:

```js
$('#regform input').on('keypress', function() {
    if($("[name='firstname']").val()!="" && $("[name='email']").val()!="" && $("[name='password']").val()!="") {
        $(".submit .myButton").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="regform" method="post" action="http://blahblah.com/signup">
  <div class="steps step1">
    <label>Your Gender?</label>
    <div name="gender">
      <div class="man-btn color" value="1">
        <span>Man</span>
        <div class="man"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="woman-btn" value="2">
        <span>Woman</span>
        <div class="woman"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="steps step2">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="steps step3">
    <label>What is Your Date of Birth?</label>
    <select name="dobday" id="dobday" class="required">
   <option value="">Day</option>
   <option value="1">01</option>
   <option value="2">02</option>
   <option value="3">03</option>
   <option value="4">04</option>
   <option value="5">05</option>
   <option value="6">06</option>
   <option value="7">07</option>
   <option value="8">08</option>
   <option value="9">09</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="23">23</option>
   <option value="24">24</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="26">26</option>
   <option value="27">27</option>
   <option value="28">28</option>
   <option value="29">29</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
    <select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth" class="required">
   <option value="">Month</option>
   <option value="1">January</option>
   <option value="2">February</option>
   <option value="3">March</option>
   <option value="4">April</option>
   <option value="5">May</option>
   <option value="6">June</option>
   <option value="7">July</option>
   <option value="8">August</option>
   <option value="9">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
    <select name="dobyear" id="dobyear" class="required">
   <option value="">Year</option>
   <?php for($x=date("Y") - 18; $x >= 1918; $x--): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
   <?php endfor; ?>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="steps step4">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="steps step5">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="error">This field is required</div>
</form>
<div class="submit">
 <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Next" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.regform input').on('click', function() {
        if($(".firstname").val()!="" && $(".email").val()!="" && $(".password").val()!="") {
            $(".submit .myButton").show();
        )}; 
    });
```

Comment: How can you answer a question without first seeing the HTML&CSS? And where's the explanation of that code? Please read [answer] (And read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem))

Comment: Thank you for giving me the info .  I have just answer on basis of the question and i did not need to see the html  . This code dose not need a any explanation plane and simple old code .

Comment: Please do try and explain your code, even if it's plain and simple (Remember that it might look simple **to you** but it might not be that trivial to the OP). I didn't downvote BTW